# How to set up a VR Simulator in Unity (without VR headset)

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

We just started a group project and we have a full working VR Environment (with movements, hand-signs, pick-up items, etc.) but we are mostly working online and not everyone has a VR Headset, so we are trying to find a VR Simulator and implement it, at least to use it for testing.

I tried VIVE Input Utility that's in the Unity Asset Store but I couldn't find a proper video or statement explaining how to set it up. Any ideas what I can do?